# Carriage Returns in ITestActionResult.ErrorMessage

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using the TFS API 2010 to insert several error messages into a `ITestActionResult`. If I do this with the TestRunner (Add Comment) and read the field (ErrorMessage) with the API the string looks like this: `"Line1\r\nLine1\r\n"...`

If I set the ErrorMessage with TFS API like this:
`actionResult.ErrorMessage = "Line1\r\nLine2\r\n"`, the `"\r\n"` sequence will be ignored!
I also try the `Environment.NewLine` Variable, here the `"\r\n"` sequence will be treated as a string and not as a escape sequence.

How can I add new lines into `ITestActionResult.ErrorMessage` similar if I use the TestRunner and push return in a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to split the line into an array. If the type is an array you cannot use a single string.